# How to replace words after first two words

Tags: preg-replace

Let say i have the full name like: Wan Ahmad Wan Dollah Karmat.

And i want to display like: Wan Ahmad W.D.K

I tried this code:

```
preg_replace('/(.)[^\s]+\s?/', '${1}.', strtoupper($_GET['fullname']), 2)
```

But the output is: W.A.Wan Dollah Karmat

I want the first two words and shorter the rest words. please help.

Problem solved, thanks to Casimir et Hippolyte. The final code is:

```
preg_replace('~^(?:\s*\S+){1,2}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\S)\S+~', '${1}.', strtoupper($_GET['fullname']))
```

its the matter of patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the backtracking control verbs `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)` to avoid the two first words.

```
$pattern = '~^(?:\s*\S+){1,2}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\S)\S+~';
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
                                function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[1]) . '.'; },
                                $_GET['fullname'] );
```

In short:

`(*SKIP)` forces a substring that matches the preceding subpattern to not be retry if the pattern fails later.

`(*FAIL)` forces the pattern to fail.

Comment: i tried this: 
preg_replace('~^\s*\S+\s+\S+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\S)\S++~', '${1}.', strtoupper($_GET['fullname']))
its working for more than one words, but its also replace if single word. eg: Wan and output: W.

Comment: @user3613026: Ok, I will edit the pattern to deal with this case.

Comment: thanks. Anyway, how do i specify if there are changes in future? is there delimiter or something. so it will be easy to edit later. eg: the first 3 words, etc.

Comment: @user3613026: When you have carefully read the pattern, I'm sure you have noticed the quantifier `{1,2}`